# Name alias for a specialized template in C++ 11

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I'm doing this:

```
template<typename Elem, int D1=1, int D2=1, int D3=1> class matrix;
```

And have a specialization:

```
template<typename Elem> class matrix<Elem, 1, 1, 1>;
```

Now, I want to get an alias of the specialized template, like this:

```
template<typename Elem> class scalar;
```

Since it has a template parameter Elem, typedef seems don't work. And I don't want to derive the new scalar class from matrix < Elem,1,1,1>... Can I achieve this? Many thanks.

Comment: Can you use C++11? If so, `template<typename Elem> using scalar = matrix<Elem, 1, 1, 1>;`

Comment: Hi @0x499602D2. I tried it on Visual Studio 2013 but it gave errors. However according to MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx, they are supporting template alias. This is really odd...

Comment: @0x499602D2 Ah it's due to a typo. Thank you! Please post an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `using` alias:

```
template<class Elem>
using scalar = matrix<Elem, 1, 1, 1>;
```

Comment: Note: This is new with C++11.